# Using variable (input parameter) as out_name to create feature class?

Tags: arcpy, error-000354

I have a dilemma, I am trying to create a new feature class, but I want the user to be able to input the name of the new fc.

I have created the variable 'newFC' as getparameterastext(2), but how do I enter the variable into the CreateFeatureclass_management line (as the out_name)?

If I enter it as below I get an error, if I enter it as "newFC" i get a feature class named newFC.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import csv
from arcpy import da

env.overwriteOutput = True

env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)       
inputText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outpath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
newFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

textfile = open (inputText, "r+")

fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newFC, "POLYGON")
arcpy.AddField_management(newFC, "Parcel", "TEXT")       
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newFC, ["SHAPE@","Parcel"])
array = arcpy.Array()
point = arcpy.Point()

parcel = ""

for line in textfile:              
    splitline = line.split(" ")     
    if splitline[0] == "Spatial":   
        sr = int(splitline[2])      
        spatialreference = arcpy.SpatialReference(sr)   
        print "Spatial reference is", spatialreference.name  
    elif splitline[0] == "Name:":           
        parcel = splitline[1]                
    elif splitline[0] == "\n":              
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)      
        cursor.insertRow([polygon,parcel])   
        array = arcpy.Array()              
    else:
        ex = splitline[0]       
        point.X = ex[:-1]      
        point.Y = splitline[1]  
        array.add(point)        

textfile.close()    
del cursor          

arcpy.DefineProjection_management(fc, spatialreference)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
layer_name = newFC

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, layer_name)
add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(layer_name)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)

print "Success!"
```

edit:
I am adding getparameterastext(2) as a string and the error message I get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "\SNHU-LABS-UTIL2.snhu-labs.com\userprofiles$\william.herzig\Documents\programming\module_7_data\module_7_data\week7final\week7ba.py", line 17, in  fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newFC, "POLYGON") 
>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.6\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 2019, in CreateFeatureclass raise e ExecuteError: 
>   ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters Failed to execute (CreateFeatureclass).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just got it to work, I had a space in the string...replace with underscore and it worked

Answer (score 2):

From the comments it's clear that the issue is bad characters in your output name. I recommend using [ValidateTableName](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/validatetablename.htm) to ensure your inputs won't throw the exception.

```
newFc = arcpy.ValidateTableName (newFc, outPath)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newFC, "POLYGON")
```